# What's the newest way to develop gnome panel applets (using python)

Tags: python, pygtk, gnome

Today I've switched to GNOME (from XFCE) and found some of the cool stuff missing and I would like to (try to) do them on my own. I tried to find information on how to develop Gnome applets (items you place within the panel) and most likely in Python, but it's not a hard limitation.

I found the [article 'Gnome applets with Python'](http://www.pygtk.org/articles/applets_arturogf/), but it seems quite old (2004). The first thing mentioned there is `bonobo` (whatever it is), but [Gnome page on Bonobo](http://live.gnome.org/Bonobo) discourages it.

Gnome site has [a page on applet development](http://library.gnome.org/devel/panel-applet/stable/), but this one is even older (2003) and incomplete (lot of `fixme write`).

What is the current approach then? I wouldn't want to learn something outdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theres an article called [Gnome Panel Applets in Python](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=496185) from 2008 on the Ubuntu forums that may help with this.

This includes defining a bonobo component. This [Gnome documentation on applet development](http://projects.gnome.org/ORBit2/appletstutorial.html) states that

> Technically, applets are Bonobo controls embedded in the Gnome panel

So it looks like that is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else comes across this question, in the forum post linked in Robert Christie's answer a user pointed out that simply using gtk.StatusIcon() is a more portable solution if you're just looking for tray icon functionality (as opposed to say a clock, or main menu applet). Additionally, if you think you need bonobo you should probably be using D-Bus anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I meant to develop a panel applet, not a tray icon.